# Complex series should sum to zero but it's a puzzle

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-series

If we have a finite sum defined as

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=N/4}^{3N/4-1} e^{-4\pi ink/N}$$

(where $k$ is an integer and $N$ is divisible by $4$), then how can we show that this sum is equal to $0$ for any positive integer $k$?

Here's what I tried to do ($W_N$ is an $Nth$ root of unity):

$$\sum\limits_{n=N/4}^{3N/4-1} e^{-4\pi ink/N} = W_N^{-kN/2}+W_N^{-kN/2}W^{-2k}+...+W_N^{-3kN/2}W_N^{2k}=e^{\pi i k}+e^{\pi i k}e^{-4\pi ik/N}+...+e^{-3\pi ik}e^{4\pi ik/N}$$

But how does it sum up to zero? I'm totally lost.

Comment: It is zero if you change the boundaries to $\sum_{n=-N/4}^{3N/4-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$N$ is a multiple of $4$,
let
$N = 4m$.

Then,
ignoring the
$\frac1{N}$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum\limits_{n=N/4}^{3N/4-1} e^{-4\pi ink/N}
&=\sum\limits_{n=m}^{3m-1} e^{-\pi ink/m}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=m}^{3m-1} \left(e^{-\pi ik/m}\right)^n\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=m}^{3m-1} r^n
\qquad\text{where } r = e^{-\pi ik/m}\\
&=r^m\sum\limits_{n=m}^{3m-1} r^{n-m}\\
&=r^m\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2m-1} r^{n}\\
&=r^m\dfrac{r^{2m}-1}{r-1}\\
&=e^{\pi i k}\dfrac{e^{2\pi i k}-1}{r-1}
\qquad\text{since } r = e^{-\pi ik/m}\\
&= 0
\qquad\text{unless }r=1\\
\end{array}
$

If $r=1$,
then the sum is
$2m$.
This only happens if
$k/m$ is an even integer,
or
$4k/N$
is even,
which is the case pointed out
by Soke.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true. Take $N = 4, k= 2$, we get

$$\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^2 e^{- 2 \pi i n } = \frac{1}{2}$$

In general, we can always take $k = 2N/4$ and make the sum

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=N/4}^{3N/4 - 1} e^{- 2 \pi i n} = \frac{1}{2}.$$